# Oracle Apex: how to handle SSO Fallback

Tags: single-sign-on, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am working on an application at work that will currently uses our ldap to allow login. We are looking into adding the ability for Single Sign On. The concern that I am currently trying to figure out is: Does APEX support multiple login types?

If the user's SSO fails we'd like to drop them at the current ldap login page and allow them to log in that way. If anyone has any idea on how to do this, please just point me in the right direction.

I was trying to find an answer on here and google, but I must be blind or using the wrong keywords.

Thanks,
-Z

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2018/02/apex-authentication-with-microsoft-account.html and section "20.4.3.9 Social Sign-In" of https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/managing-application-attributes.htm#GUID-69485470-823B-4CC0-9E11-1CF144054F53

Basically if you are using the Social Sign-in you can switch between authentication schemes in the same APEX session.

Regards
Stephen